# how to open multiple urls using Selenium internet explorer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i would like to ask about how to open multiple Urls with internet explorer mode, i have a problem with internet explorer it doesn't save username and password every time i login i have to type them so I'm trying to use Selenium to open all DVRs urls at once with same user and password.
I'm using the below code but i stuck to open multiple tabs.
the last line of code it doesn't work either
'''button type="button" class="btn btn-primary login-btn" ng-click="login()">  </button'''

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions

edge_options = EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
edge_options.add_argument("inprivate")

username1 = "user"
password1 = "1234"

driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\\dev\\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get("http://192.168.1.50")


username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username1)
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password1)
time.sleep(3)

login = driver.find_element_by_name("login").submit()
```

Comment: _the last line of code it doesn't work either_: You need to address this issue first then only you can open multiple urls.